# my Activity is closing automattically and return to previous activity when phone sleep

Tags: android

Im starting an activity from onListItemClick Listener as shown

```
 @Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Intent n = new Intent(ResultQuestionnaireList.this,ShowResult.class);
    n.putExtra("title",""+adapter.getItem(position));
    startActivity(n);
}
```

My problem is that whenever phone makes a sleep The new activity closed and my app return to the old activity ..

Any Help please?

UPDATE :
MY second activity code

```
public class ShowResult extends AppCompatActivity {
ProgressDialog pDialog;
private String URL_GET_Ques = //Myurl;
private String URL_GET_Ques = //Myurl;
private String URL_GET_RES = //Myurl;
private ArrayList<ResultObject> res;
private ArrayList<AtomQuestionnaire> ques;
private int type;
String title= "";
String question= "";
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter;
Spinner spinner;
boolean questionReady=false;
int sortt = 1;
Spinner sortSpin ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_result);
    Intent n= getIntent();
    if(n.hasExtra("title")){
      title = n.getStringExtra("title");
    }
    questionReady=false;
     sortSpin = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerType);
    sortSpin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            // your code here
            sortt=position;
            if(questionReady &&!question.equals("")) {
                getExecuter(title, question, type, position);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            // your code here
        }

    });

   spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerQues);
     spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, android.R.id.text1);

    spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            // your code here
            if(questionReady){
        question=   parentView.getSelectedItem().toString();
            type = ques.get(position).getType();
                Log.d("type",type+"");
                getExecuter(title, question, type, sortt);
        }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            // your code here
        }

    });

    ques = new ArrayList<AtomQuestionnaire>();

    new GetQuestions(title).execute();
}
public void getExecuter(String title ,String question,int type,int sort){
    new GetResults( title,question,type,sort).execute();

}
```

}

Comment: put the overrided method in the new activity

Comment: Post error stack from log

Comment: show the code of other activity that is closing.

Comment: Now i post the second activity code